# failed to create a secret in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I’m trying to create a secret in kubernetes :

```
sudo kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

then I got this error :

`error: failed to create secret Post "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?fieldManager=kubectl-create&fieldValidation=Strict": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused`

kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
```

any one could help pleaes ?